# Creating an anonymous type dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, anonymous-types

I wanna create an anonymous type that I can set the property name dynamically. it doesn't have to be an anonymous type. All I want to achieve is set any objects property names dynamically. It can be ExpandoObject, but dictionary will not work for me.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Why does a dictionary not work for you?

Comment: cos i have to bind it to a telerik grid's datasource and also i add grid's columns dynamically.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Only `ExpandoObject` can have dynamic properties.

**Edit**:
Here is an example of [Expand Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) usage (from its MSDN description):

```
dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();
sampleObject.TestProperty = "Dynamic Property"; // Setting dynamic property.
Console.WriteLine(sampleObject.TestProperty );
Console.WriteLine(sampleObject.TestProperty .GetType());
// This code example produces the following output:
// Dynamic Property
// System.String

dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string, object>)test).Add("DynamicProperty", 5);
Console.WriteLine(test.DynamicProperty);
```

Comment: yes i know about that. but can i set ExpandoObjects property from a string array for example?

Comment: ... well, or any other type implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.

Comment: ExpandoObject implements `IDictionary<string,object>`, so yes you can treat it as a dictionary to populate it.

Comment: what i am actually trying to say is can i set ExpandoObject 's property name dynamically? if i can can you please suply an example?

Comment: Added example of expado object's usage

Comment: thanks a lot man but this is not what i want unfortunately. i want to set the property name dynamically... In this case ".test"...

Comment: I've added another example. If it is not what you need then what do you mean under dynamic?

Answer (score 43):

You can cast `ExpandoObject` to a dictionary and populate it that way, then the keys that you set will appear as property names on the ExpandoObject...

```
dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();

IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)data;
dictionary.Add("FirstName", "Bob");
dictionary.Add("LastName", "Smith");

Console.WriteLine(data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName);
```

Comment: +1 That is pretty wild and I didn't know dynamics had this capability.  Other languages have similar capabilities, and this certainly would have a few great use cases. On the other hand, it could also be abused pretty terribly as well, and should be used with due respect.