#  Exporting dataTable to dataGridView, not working

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable, full-outer-join

I've been working on a project that takes two csv file as input, imported in dataTable.
Now I wanted to join those two and finally show the joined one to a dataGridView.

The program is working fine till the import part.

The code that I've created so far does not show any error but it's not working, I mean, my destination Data Grid View remains blank.

Please observe the following code and provide some solution that works.
Best regards.

P.S: I'm trying to do the Full Outer Join at here.

```
var tbl1 = tb1;
var tbl2 = tb2;
var res1 = from t2 in tbl2.AsEnumerable()
           join t1 in tbl1.AsEnumerable() on t2["BBL"] equals t1["BBL"] into g
           from t1 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where t1 == null
           select t2;

dataGridView3.DataSource = res1;
```

Comment: BBL is a column that I want to compare.

Comment: The grid view is showing these columns with no cell/row:

RowError | RowState | Table | HasError

Comment: check dataGridView3.Rows.Count

Answer (score 0):

You must create your columns or copy the schema for res1.

Example:

```
res1.columns.Add("RowError",typeof(string));
```

Comment: Oh by the way, the row count is displaying 0 :(

Comment: That is right because you didn't define the datatable's schema. You can add the code before dataGridView3.DataSource = res1;

Comment: It is not letting me to insert it. Showing the red curly underline of error beneath the columns

Comment: What is the error? You may define the datatable as DataTable res1 rather than var res1.

Comment: If I make the res1 as DataTable then it's giving another error. Can't read my queries.

Comment: You can use var res1, but afterwards you may convert it to a datatable and bind it to the DataGridView3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/convert-a-linq-query-resultset-to-a-datatable/ and google search.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `res1` is a collection of `DataRow` and its non indexed [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) are being rendered as columns.

## Solution 1

You can select an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) of object with the row's contents as its properties.

e.g.,

```
var tbl1 = tb1;
var tbl2 = tb2;
var res1 = from t2 in tbl2.AsEnumerable()
           join t1 in tbl1.AsEnumerable() on t2["BBL"] equals t1["BBL"] into g
           from t1 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where t1 == null
           select new { Amount = t2["amount"], Payee = t2["payee"] };
```

where `amount` and `payee` are two columns in `tb2`.

If you set `AutoGenerateColumns` on `dataGridView3` to `true`, then the names of the properties of this anonymous class (viz. `Amount` and `Payee`) will be used as column names.

## Solution 2

As in your comment you said that you wanted to show all columns, so here is another less elegant solution (please leave your Linq expression as is):

```
foreach (DataColumn dCol in tbl1.Columns)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dCol.ColumnName, dCol.Caption);
}

foreach (var s in res1)
{
    foreach (var item in res1)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.ItemArray);
    }
}
```

You should remove the `dataGridView3.DataSource = res1;` if you go ahead with this approach.

Comment: What if I've to select all the columns inside t2 table?

Comment: @SaffanAlvy See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024754/creating-an-anonymous-type-dynamically.

Comment: Can't understand it that how it regards this problem.

Comment: @SaffanAlvy Please ignore the previous. I just tested. Cannot bind a datagridview with ExpandoObject's dynamic properties. I am sure there is a workaround. Meanwhile, posted a dirty solution.

Comment: @SaffanAlvy dynamic objects can be defined at run-time. You can add properties to them and set/get those properties too. I was attempting to create a dynamic object from your columns but that didn't work. Perhaps someday I will find a solution on those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your try but I needed it today.

Comment: Hey man! I think it's working but, lol... was adding the columns and rows but suddenly says out of memory, maybe an infinite loop.

Comment: @SaffanAlvy That should be a different question. Debugging OOM exceptions/errors is a very different topic.

Comment: @SaffanAlvy Is the OOM deterministic after setting the datasource or does it happen randomly?