# Multi sums into  one anonymous type with linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have this simple datatable :

```
 type (string)   |       cnt (int)     
_____________________________________
aaa                         1
aaa                         2
aaa                         10
bbb                         1
bbb                         1
```

I want to produce **1** anonymous type  like this :

```
{
sumAAA= 13 , sumBBB=2  //13=1+2+10....
}
```

something like : (psuedo code )

```
var obj= dt.AsEnumerable().Select(f=> new { sumAAA =f.sumOfCntOfAaa , sumBBB =f.sumOfCntOfBbb });
```

any help ?

edit , this will help you

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
    dt.Columns.Add("cnt", typeof (int));
    dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof (string));
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["cnt"] = 1;
    row["type"] = "aaa";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["cnt"] = 2;
    row["type"] = "aaa";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["cnt"] = 10;
    row["type"] = "aaa";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["cnt"] = 1;
    row["type"] = "bbb";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["cnt"] = 1;
    row["type"] = "bbb";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: You want to turn rows to properties, essentially denormalizing, or transposing the schema of,  the data?

Comment: is `bb` to be summed with `bbb`?

Comment: @Jodrell its also bbb. fixed. thanks.

Comment: You can group the data as in Scorpi0's answer, but then you would have to dynamically create an anonymous type which would not be much good for coding against, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4024754/659190. Unless you know what groups will be present in the data at compile time?

Comment: @Jodrell I just want an object which contains both sums. I don't want to use any loops.

Comment: Will they always be named `aaa` and `bbb`?

Comment: @Jodrell yes. the types suppose to be hard coded in the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Be dynamic:**

```
dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
dt.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("type"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(g=> ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result)["sum" + g.Key.ToUpper()] = g.Sum(r=>r.Field<Int32>("cnt")));

Console.WriteLine(result.sumAAA);
Console.WriteLine(result.sumBBB);
```

Works for a arbitary number of different `type`s, not only `aaa` and `bbb`.

**Output:**

> 13
>   2

Comment: @Royi Namir, its what you orginally asked for but needlessly pushes all your type checking to runtime so potentially very "not nice". However, is a good answer to the question. Why not write this with javascript.

Comment: Isn't `r.Field<String>("type")` is like   `r["type"].ToString()`?

Comment: @Royi Not exactly. `Field<String>` casts the value to `String`, while `ToString()`, well, is a call to `ToString()`. `Field<T>` It will also convert `DBNull` to `null`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus How can I safely get a property from expando , but checking before if the property exists ? do if i try myExpando.NoitExists - it won't go bang ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Either use [RuntimeOps.ExpandoTryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989438.aspx) or just cast the `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionay<String, object>` and use either [IDictionay.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.contains.aspx) or [IDictionay.Keys.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.keys.aspx).

Comment: @BigYellowCactus I was just tesing it without dynamic by `Dictionary <string,object> result = new Dictionary <string,object>();` and it works. So why did you use dynamic ?

Comment: ` Dictionary<string,object> result = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dt.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("type"))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(g=> ((IDictionary<String, Object>)result)["sum" + g.Key.ToUpper()] = g.Sum(r=>r.Field<Int32>("cnt")));
 
 
 Console.WriteLine(result["sumAAA"] +"     "+result["sumBBB"]);`

Comment: Of course you could use a plain old Dictionary. But when using a dynamic ExpandoObject, you can write `result.sumAAA` instead of `result["sumAAA"]`. I thought that was what you wanted to achieve :-)

Answer (score 4):

In an assembly all anonymous types with the same properties with the same type and order are the same type. So it is possible to create a new instance of the *same* anonymous type:

***Version One***

```
var totals = new {
    SumAs = 0,
    SumBs = 0
};

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => {
    totals = new {
        SumAs = totals.SumAs + (dr["type"].Equals("aaa") ? (int)dr["cnt"] : 0),
        SumBs = totals.SumBs + (dr["type"].Equals("bbb") ? (int)dr["cnt"] : 0)
    };
    return totals;
}).Last();
```

But with aggregate one can do better...

***Version Two***

```
var result2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(new { SumAs = 0, SumBs = 0 }, (total, dr) => {
    return new {
        SumAs = total.SumAs + (dr["type"].Equals("aaa") ? (int)dr["cnt"] : 0),
        SumBs = total.SumBs + (dr["type"].Equals("bbb") ? (int)dr["cnt"] : 0)
    };
});
```

***Update: Complete Sample of Using Version 2***

(Tuples used because they are much easier to set up):

Paste into a default C# Console project:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var input = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => Tuple.Create(x, x*x));

        var res = input.Aggregate(new { Firsts = 0, Seconds = 0}, (total, val) => {
            return new {
                Firsts = total.Firsts + val.Item1,
                Seconds = total.Seconds + val.Item2
            };
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Firsts: {0}; Seconds: {1}", res.Firsts, res.Seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: This version 2 looks nice but... it is simply can't compile! The reason is that the type checker fail to unify the two similar anonymous class... -1.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Just tested here (using Tuples rather than a DataTable as input as easier to set up): no problem. The approach does depend on both initial and increment definitions of the anonymous type having both the same names and type in the same order (eg. if the content of the input is `double` ensure the initial value is created with doubles). I'll add my test code to the answer.

Comment: @Richard This seems to be an issue of version of C# compiler. In Visual studio 2010 this is an error, whilst in MonoDevelop 4.0.12 this is not  (and it seems to assume that anonymous types with the same fields are the same). So you might need to update your answer.

Comment: @EarthEngine: It could easily be version dependent, but without spending time working out what IDE, BCL or language feature that determines it I would rather focus on the current version (and perhaps previous) of tools. (Older versions: create and use a named struct, can be a private member of the containing class.)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use 2 LINQ statements?

```
var obj = new {
    sumAAA = dt.Rows
        .Where(x => x["type"] == "aaa")
        .Sum(y => (int) y["cnt"]), 
    sumBBB = dt.Rows
        .Where(x => x["type"] == "bbb")
        .Sum(y => (int) y["cnt"])
};
```

Or a simple for loop?

```
int sAAA = 0; int sBBB = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if(row["type"] == "aaa")
        sAAA += (int) row["cnt"];
    else
        sBBB += (int) row["cnt"];
}

var obj = new { sumAAA = sAAA, sumBBB = sBBB };
```

**EDIT:** Oops... Anonymous objects are immutable, changed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = dt.AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy(row => row["type"])
          .Select(grp => new { Type = grp.Key, 
                             Sum = grp.Sum(c => (int)c["cnt"])
          });
```

This will give you a list of anonymous {type, sum}, that must be a good start!

Comment: I want **one** anonymous type with both results .