# LINQ C# to Array JSON Object in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

My intention is to use LINQ query then return JSON for MVC controller.

format I want to achieve:

```
[{ 
   "A" : {"Count": 2 },
   "B" : {"Count": 7 },
}]
```

or

```
[{ 
   "A" : [{"Count": 2 }],
   "B" : [{"Count": 7 }],
}]
```

But so far I only can make it like this:

```
[{ 
   {"MG":"A", "Count": 2 },
   {"MG":"B", "Count": 7 }
}]
```

And I try something like below, it get error

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

```
public JsonResult groupByTable()
{
    IQueryable<tblSAPMessage> v = sapMessages();
    var data = v.GroupBy(g => g.MaterialGroup)
        .Select(g => new { g.Key.ToString() = new {
                    Count = g.Count()
                }});
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Appreciate if someone can point me to correct direction. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly you need dynamic property names. You could achieve it only using [Expando](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) Object

You could try something around these lines.

```
dynamic mytype = new ExpandoObject();
var data = v.GroupBy(g => g.MaterialGroup)
        .Select(g => (IDictionary<string, object>) mytype.Add(g.Key.ToString(),
        new {Count =  g.Count()}));
```

you could look at these answers for more inspiration [Dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024754/creating-an-anonymous-type-dynamically)

Comment: I feel like I got your idea, but somehow, I play around with the code, still not able to make it. Still having same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json.net / newtonsoft to create a json object

```
using Json.net
var countObject = new JObject ();
countObject.Add("count",2);
var jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.Add("a", countObject);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, yr method will need a loop, but i look for method using linq.

Comment: Have you tried using the linq foreach?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx