# How to create an anonymous type using codedom

Tags: c#, codedom

Essentially I am aiming to get something like the following code as output from my codedom:

```
var foo = new { variable1 = "value", variable2 = 5 };
```

I won't just be using it for a variable assignment but I wanted a simple example of how to create an anonymous type. I'm not sure that this exact code is possible to achieve but if there's some kind of work around you could point me in the direction of I would be much obliged.

I've had a look at the `CodeObjectCreateExpression` and I don't think that's going to do what I'm looking for and I can't find anything else that comes close.

Thanks in advance for all and any help.

Comment: I guess, you should use tuple instead.

Comment: why not play around dynamic types? Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740021/how-to-dynamic-new-anonymous-class

Comment: CodeDom is a thing from the past. It has never really followed .NET (read "C#") evolutions. Microsoft has put all efforts on Roslyn instead. The only solution is to use CodeDom snippets

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @Innat3 I've seen that ExpandoObject around, fairly new ish to C# and haven't used dynamics much before, is that an alternative I could maybe use? How would I go about it?

Comment: You cannot return anonymous type, for example, from method. So, you should use `System.Tuple` or `dynamic` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeDOM attempts to be language-neutral and hasn't been updated for a very long time, so I don't think you can use any of its built-in types to do this. But you can use `CodeSnippetExpression` to inject this code as string:

```
var expression = new CodeSnippetExpression("new { variable1 = \"value\", variable2 = 5 }");
var statement = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement("var", "foo", expression);
```

Comment: That'll do for the case I've got, didn't know you could do that! Thanks