# C# dynamic: Assign properties dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, dynamic-keyword

I am writing a wrapper around some data library that executes sql statements and returns results.

The `ExecuteQuery` command should ideally return an `IEnumerable<T>` depending on what type of object the query results map to. The problem is that I cannot know what type this would be and therefore I would rather return a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` type.

This is all good so far except that I want the dynamic objects properties to be the same as the columns being queried for but I cannot find anyway to assign this, I currently have all the column names in an array col[] e.g.

```
dynamic obj = new {} as dynamic;
for(int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++){
    //say col[i] == 'id', I want obj.id = someValue 
    obj.? = someValue;  ???
}
```

I hope this is clear. I hope it's not impossible!

p.s. I am writing this for WP7 so my options are severely limited, it might be good to keep this in mind.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @DanielHilgarth, my typing was just all over the place

Comment: Similar, non-wp: [Dynamically set the property name of a C# anonymous type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642733/dynamically-set-the-property-name-of-a-c-sharp-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic` is not applicable in your case. You use `dynamic` when you know the property name at *compile time* but not the actual type that property will be defined on.

If you know the property name only at runtime you will have to use ordinary reflection, something like this:

```
obj.GetType()
   .GetProperty(col[i])
   .SetValue(obj, someValue);
```

Please note that `dynamic obj = new {} as dynamic;` makes absolutely no sense. This will create an anonymous type without any properties. Assigning it to a `dynamic` variable doesn't change the fact that it doesn't have - and never will - any properties.

If you are trying to dynamically add properties to an object, you might want to use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Usage would be like this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
for(int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
{
    obj.Add(col[i], someValue);
}

return (dynamic)obj;
```

Comment: Err, so are you saying that assuming a different scenario, if I did obj.SomeProperty = "some value"; that obj would still not have any properties?
The reason I did that was so that the reference would not be null!

Comment: @ObiOnuorah: Indeed. You would simply get a `RuntimeBinderException`: *'`<>f__AnonymousType0`' does not contain a definition for 'SomeProperty'*.

Comment: @ObiOnuorah: What are you trying to achieve here anyway?

Comment: Also, your answer seems to assume that obj already has a property called col[i] which it doesn't hence the need for a dynamic object. I tried using an ExpandoObject but I do not get this type when I add System.Dynamic to my references....any thoughts?

Comment: Like the question says, I am writing a wrapper for a data provider. I want the consumer to be able to give me a sql select statement with columns and get back an object collection with properties matching the column names that was queried.

Comment: @ObiOnuorah: ExpandoObject should work. See also my updated answer. Just add a reference to System.Core to your project and add `using System.Dynamic;` to the top of your *.cs file. But I am not sure about Windows Phone 7 - sorry.